# Receive mail in localhost XAMPP PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, smtp, xampp

I am trying to receive mails in my local server running XAMPP. I have Mercury and outlook configured and running according to this: http://system66.blogspot.in/2010/01/how-to-send-mail-from-localhost-with.html

My goal is that, I must be able to send a mail from xyz@somedomain.com to someaddress@localhost and I want to parse the received mail and store it in a MySQL DB.

I saw many references telling how to send mail from localhost (using gmail's smtp server using sendmail) but I dont find any resource telling me how to receive mail from anyone onto my local computer. Once I receive the mail to my PC, I can parse it and store it in DB. The only problem is getting the mail. Please help me out.

PS: I have configured php.ini and sendmail.ini files for doing the operations.
Firewalls are disabled and ports are available.

If you dont understand my question, imagine my pc as a mail server which is trying to get the mail sent to xyz@myserver.com

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** : You need to configure DNS for your mail server. [Take a look at this.](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/how-to-run-your-own-e-mail-server-with-your-own-domain-part-1/)  Hope it would help.

You need to open port in your router & PC firewall in order to get requests from outside and a mail server.

Comment: ports are open. but not sure how to get the request will come to my local server

Comment: Tell me how are you sending mail to your local server? Did you configured any domain name with your server? How are you managing DNS records?

Comment: i have not configured any domain since i thought i would use my public ip address for now instead of domain. and my problem is somewhat associated with dns records. since i dont know if i have to configure any mx record in my local machine. sending from my pc wont be a problem. only receiving to my pc is the problem

Comment: So this is the problem !!! YES you need configure MX records in order to setup complete email server. The problem with setting Email server is exactly same as you are facing. **It is not as simple as configuring web server.** E-mail is a lot more complex, with many more moving parts. I will update my answer soon to provide you easiest guide for setting up email server & DNS record.